# Title attribute (HTML) doesn't show tooltip in PyQt4

Tags: html, pyqt, title, qwebview

I'm using a QWebView to show some HTML:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys

class PlayerStats(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PlayerStats, self).__init__()
        self.show()

content= '<span title="Hello !">Hover on me</span>'
app=QApplication(sys.argv)
playerStats= PlayerStats()
playerStats.setHtml(content)
app.exec_()
```

where content= `<span title="Hello !">Hover on me</span>`

But when I hover over the span, nothing happens. Is they an option to show tooltips with titles ?

Comment: Works as expected for me on Linux and WinXP.

Comment: You're right, my example works, but it doesn't in my code, and I don't know why...

Comment: Actually it didn't work because I rewrited the mouseMoveEvent, mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent, and didn't call the super method before